# Receving email using Alibaba Cloud Direct Mail?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am curious to know why Direct mail doesn't support the incoming emails to the same email address used to trigger the notifications. Why do we need to receive on another email?

Is there any architectural limitation to this in terms of security/functionality etc..

Answer (score 2):

Providing email services that includes receiving emails is a different level of service then sending emails and far more complicated internally. DirectMail is a message sending service, not an email server. Alibaba does offer a full email service for its customers in China.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting and receiving emails is far more complex. If you were to provide a service to send and receive emails you have to have an api waiting for an email to arrive, another to retrieve emails from the storage when the user requests, and another to send out the emails.

On the other hand DirectMail just has one service send out either predefined emails that get set up ahead of time or emails that are sent from Function Compute. This way there is no waiting/server overhead, just send and done.